# struts2: On checkbox click control go to action written in url tag like <s:url action="smactiion">

Tags: struts2

On clicking the anchor tag link “click me” control goes to the action defined in `<s:url>` tag and sends all the param values defined under `<s:url>` tag . See below -

```
<s:url id="matchId" action="someAction">
<s:param name="QuotFileName" value="FileName"/>
<s:param name="QuotContentType" value="ContentType"/>
</s:url>
<s:a href="%{ matchId }">click me</s:a>
```

Its all running well. 
But I want to do the same thing using checkbox i.e `<s:checkbox>` instead of anchor tag i.e `<s:a>.`
But there is no href attribute in `<s:checkbox>` tag… See below code -

```
<s:url id="matchId" action="someAction">
<s:param name="QuotFileName" value="FileName"/>
<s:param name="QuotContentType" value="ContentType"/>
</s:url>
<s:checkbox href="%{ matchId }"></s:checkbox>
```

Please suggest what should I use inplace of ‘href ‘attribute of `<s:checkbox>.`

Answer (score 1):

Can you use the onclick attribute to call some Javascript that sets window.location to whatever you want?

http://struts.apache.org/2.1.6/docs/checkbox.html